# How to mark dot on specific dates in JTAppleCalendar

Tags: ios, swift3, jtapplecalendar

I have an array with 5 dates. I am using [JTAppleCalendar](https://github.com/patchthecode/JTAppleCalendar). How can I mark dates on this calendar. I don't want to select those dates. I added a "dot" to the cell. I want to visibility on this dot for those specific dates. How can I do this?

Comment: In the `willDisplayCell` method for JTAppleCalendar. Do a compare on the dates in your array to the date parameter that is received in the method `func calendar(_ calendar: JTAppleCalendarView, willDisplayCell cell: JTAppleDayCellView, date: Date, cellState: CellState) {`

Comment: A video explaining your exact situation can be found --> [HERE] <-- (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CQNotydm58s)

Comment: you want to create your dot in the customCell that you make for your JTAppleCalendar. Then, the video ^^ shown above by patchthecode will show you how to compare the date of the cell to your dates to change the hidden property of your dot.

Comment: @iOSCalendarpatchthecode.com is this YouTube link private ? It is showing unavailable. It will be helpful if you could provide available link. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: link was removed because it caused more trouble than help. Because the library is constantly being updated, but the video cannot. The tutorial here says exactly how to do it. --> https://patchthecode.com/jtapplecalendar-home/adding-events/